# How to change a var in the "beforeSend: function()" using ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax contact form that uses the beforeSend function to check if the inputs are valid (and passes the params to a PHP file that sends the email).

For some reason I always get false instead of true when the inputs are valid, and I'm guessing that it's because I cant change the variables instead of the beforeSend function. How can I change the variables inside the beforeSend function?

```
//Gets a name var and checks if it's valid
function IsName(name) {
    if (name == null || name == "") {
        return false;
    }
}   

//Gets an email var and checks if it's valid
function IsEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  console.log(regex.test('function: '+email));
  return regex.test(email);
}


//Send button for the "contact form".
$('#sendBtn').click(function(){
    //get info 
    var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var text = $("#text").val();
    var validation = 0;


    //send info to php 
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() {
            if ( IsName(fullname) == false ) {
                $('#contactNameUnsuccess').show("slow");
                $('.form_content').hide("slow");
                validation = 0;
                return;
            }
            else if ( IsName(email) == false ) {
                $('#contactNoEmailUnsuccess').show("slow");
                $('.form_content').hide("slow");
                validation = 0;
                return;
            } 
            else if ( IsEmail(email) == false ) {
                $('#aboutEmailUnsuccess').show("slow");
                $('.form_content').hide("slow");
                validation = 0;
                return;
            } else if ( (IsName(fullname) == true ) && ( IsName(email) == true ) && ( IsEmail(email) == true )  ) {
                validation = 1;
                return;
            }
            console.log('Validation response: '+validation);
        }, 
        url: document.location.protocol+'//'+document.location.host+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', 
        type: "POST", 
        data: ({ "action": "submit_contact_form", "fullname": fullname, "email": email, "text": text, "validation": validation }), 
        success: function (results){
            if ( IsEmail(email) == true ) {
                //hide table
                $('.form_content').hide('slow', function() {
                    $('.form_content').hide( "slow" );
                  });
                //show textboxes
                $('#aboutSuccess').show("slow");
                $("#aboutSuccess").append("<iframe id=\"pixel-thing\" src=\"http://example.con/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/thePixel.html\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\"  border=\"0\" frameBorder=\"0\"></iframe>");
            }
        }
    }); 

});
```

Comment: You need to share your methods to validate too. Maybe `( IsName(email) == true ) && ( IsEmail(email) == true )` both can not be `true`. BTW, returning nothing from beforeSend won't avoid request to be send

Comment: I added the 2 functions. 
It always returns the value of "validation" to 0

Comment: But `IsName()` return false or undefined, which is falsy. You need to return true from this function, e.g: `return !(name == null || name == "");`. That's said, as all string except empty one is truly in javascript, `return name;` would be enough, meaning that your IsName() function is useless here. So e.g: `if ( IsName(fullname) == false ) {...}` could be just `if ( fullname ) {...}`

Comment: not sure I understand

Comment: I changes it to 
`(name != null || name != "")` 
and in the end `return true;`

Comment: @A.Wolff not working for me :'(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this? -

Correct the `IsName` function -

```
  //Gets a name var and checks if it's valid
  function IsName(name) {
      if (name == null || name == "") {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
```

Do check outside -

```
function Validate(){
    if ( IsName(fullname) == false ) {
                $('#contactNameUnsuccess').show("slow");
                $('.form_content').hide("slow");
                validation = 0;
            }
            else if ( IsName(email) == false ) {
                $('#contactNoEmailUnsuccess').show("slow");
                $('.form_content').hide("slow");
                validation = 0;
            } 
            else if ( IsEmail(email) == false ) {
                $('#aboutEmailUnsuccess').show("slow");
                $('.form_content').hide("slow");
                validation = 0;
            } else if ( (IsName(fullname) == true ) && ( IsName(email) == true ) && ( IsEmail(email) == true )  ) {
                validation = 1;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
}

//send info to php 

var validation = Validate();
$.ajax({
    url: document.location.protocol+'//'+document.location.host+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', 
    type: "POST", 
    data: ({ "action": "submit_contact_form", "fullname": fullname, "email": email, "text": text, "validation": validation }), 
    success: function (results){
        if ( IsEmail(email) == true ) {
            //hide table
            $('.form_content').hide('slow', function() {
                $('.form_content').hide( "slow" );
              });
            //show textboxes
            $('#aboutSuccess').show("slow");
            $("#aboutSuccess").append("<iframe id=\"pixel-thing\" src=\"http://example.con/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/thePixel.html\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\"  border=\"0\" frameBorder=\"0\"></iframe>");
        }
    }
});
```